# Want my program to enrypt information by shifting english alphabet 8 positions thus A become I

Tags: c++, encryption

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int i, x;
    char str[100];
    cout << "Please enter a string:\t";
    cin >> str;

    cout << "\nPlease choose following options:\n";
    cout << "1 = Encrypt the string.\n";
    cout << "2 = Decrypt the string.\n";
    cin >> x;

    //using switch case statements
    switch (x)
    {
    //first case for encrypting a string
    case 1:
        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i + 8)
            str[i] = str[i] + 8;
        cout << "\nEncrypted string: " << str << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); i + 8)
            str[i] = str[i] - 8;
        cout << "\nDecrypted string: " << str << endl;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "\nInvalid Input !!!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to make it encrypt engish alphabet by shifting 8 position thus A become I and B becomes j
But it seems not to be working I don't know why

Comment: I suggest that you learn to use a *debugger*

Comment: Why do you do `i + 8` in the loop increment? That's actually going to loop infinitely. You probably just want `++i`

Comment: The debugger don't show any errors

Comment: Think on what happens to the letter Z. Debuggers to not show errors. They allow you to run the program at a rate you can keep up with and inspect the state of the program (look at the variables, etc...) as it runs. Typical usage is to step through the program line by line and see what the effect is. If what happens is not what you expect to happen, you've found a bug.

Comment: Debugger won't *show* you errors, it will help you *find* them. If you go step by step through your code, you will quickly notice that you only modify every 8th character, that `Z` gets changed into something weird when it's encrypted...

Comment: Search the internet for "Caesar Cipher".  Same algorithm, different amount of shifting.

Comment: Usually, the remainder operator, `%`, is used with shifting encryption.  For example, `str[i] = (str[i] + 1) % 8;`  This is known as a rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't actually looping through the array at all. `i + 8` does not change the value of `i` at all. What you want is `++i` in order to increment `i` by one, there-by changing all the elements of your array.

Example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    int i, x;
    char str[100];
    cout << "Please enter a string:\t";
    cin >> str;

    cout << "\nPlease choose following options:\n";
    cout << "1 = Encrypt the string.\n";
    cout << "2 = Decrypt the string.\n";
    cin >> x;

    //using switch case statements
    switch (x)
    {
    //first case for encrypting a string
    case 1:
        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); ++i)
            str[i] = str[i] + 8;
        cout << "\nEncrypted string: " << str << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        for (i = 0; (i < 100 && str[i] != '\0'); ++i)
            str[i] = str[i] - 8;
        cout << "\nDecrypted string: " << str << endl;
        break;

    default:
        cout << "\nInvalid Input !!!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Working example (uncomment the un-encrypted string, and comment the encrypted ones to reverse): https://godbolt.org/z/677GMr